# How to use fmt:formatNumber with 2 decimal

Tags: format, jstl, number-formatting

I have value 6666666666666666.6 and using fmt:formatNumber to format on jsp(jstl)

```html
<fmt:formatNumber type="NUMBER"
                  minFractionDigits="2"
                  maxFractionDigits="2"
                  value="6666666666666666.6"/>
```

Display result: 6,666,666,666,666,667.00

Result expect: 6,666,666,666,666,666.60

Please share me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? can we see your code?

Comment: sorry. i was add my code. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the **type** from `number` into `currency`?

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="CURRENCY"
                  minFractionDigits="2"
                  maxFractionDigits="2"
                  value="6666666666666666.6"/>
```

Comment: Why should you use currency to format a regular number?

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="N-15-digits" value=${666,666,666,666,666.6}/>
<c:set var="N-16-digits" value=${6,666,666,666,666,666.6}/>     
<fmt:formatNumber value="${N-(0.1-(N%0.1))%0.1}"  type="number"  minFractionDigits="2"/>
```

This solution could always show without rounding If input value under 16 digit, result comparison is on following.

N-15-digits would show

> 666,666,666,666,666.60

N-16-digits would show

> 6,666,666,666,666,667.00

Comment: Mean is this problem can't resolving?

Comment: @IfElse still have to figure out why over 16 digit isn't work anymore for this method,